# Tuning JVM cloudbees

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, cloudbees

Well, i have a app running on cloudbees, my app need some  extra java memory, this app use (hibernate and spring).
Reading in other post and the cloudbees document, i think the way to change a max and min of memory on JVM is by this way: "`bees app:deploy -a account/appId -R JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m  /target/app.ear`" but when i do this and try to run the app, throw the next exception

**Error occurred during initialization of VM**

**Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified**

What i´m doing wrong and what can i do to resolve this problem?

On adding, i'm using **Jboss** and when run "bees app:info" the info is the next:

Application : account/appId Title : account/appId Created : Mon Aug 04 11:49:18 EDT 2014 Status : active URL : ... clusterSize : 1 container : java_small containerType : jboss71 hibernateTimeout: 7200 jvmPermSize : 256 **maxMemory : 256** proxyBuffering : false securityMode : PUBLIC

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i found my error.
I solved this problem paying a account in cloudbees. A free account doesn't allow increment a JVM memory above 256mb. When i try increment this parameter Xms512m, the minimum memory exceed maximum memory